# iPad running iOS5 loads large image with smaller dimension

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, canvas

I'm building a multiplatform HTML5 canvas game with EaselJS (although I tested without using this library and the problem persists);

I'm loading an image in that is 1280 x 1800 and then rendering it to the canvas.

This runs as expected on all devices except the ipad 1st gen running iOS5.

It loads and draws the image to canvas at 640x900...

I alerted Image.width with a result of 640, so I don't think it has anything to do with the actual rendering to canvas but rather limitations to image size with iOS5?

As a work around I am scaling the image up, so it just appears lower quality on this particular device, but I'm looking for a solution or at least explanation of why this is happening!

here is an example of the problem:
http://kokodev.co.uk/ipadcanvasimageproblem/

---

I also connected the iPad to the xCode organizer console to see if it reported any errors or memory warnings, but it did not!

Comment: I just got the same problem. Have you found a better idea/solution ?

Comment: @aIMAC unfortunately not! :(